# db.Prepare("INSERT INTO ? VALUES ()") not working

Tags: mysql, go, mariadb

I'm wondering if there was any possibility to use this function:

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO ? VALUES ()", tableName)

fatal(err)
```

What I try to do is: Getting a table name and trying, with go, to create a new element in the database with default option. (database = MySQL)

If you have any idea about why it isn't working or how I can do that I would be really greatfull

Comment: can you show us the error trace?

Comment: Not possible, you cannot parameterize table names, nor column names, placeholders are for values not tables, columns, etc. To do what you want do this: `db.Prepare("INSERT INTO "+tableName+" VALUES ()")` and make sure to sanitize the tableName value if it's user input.

Comment: Ensure that you are supplying a full table name that exists.  Mysql and I'm pretty sure Maria require specification of the database and table if their are multiple on the server.

Comment: To expand on @mkopriva's comment, there is currently no standard way to quote/escape/sanitize an identifier (but [discussions have been underway](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18478) for awhile) so you'll have to consult the MySQL/MariaDB documentation to write your own quoting function if you can't trust `tableName` to be safe already.